# Input and output a simple array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm taking intro to java, and we are to write a simple program to create an array with 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 be able to input those same values and output them. I can't seem to get it to print all five, it only prints the number 11.

Here's the code and output, if anyone can help i'd appreciate it.

```
int[] MyList = new int [] {11,12,13,14,15};
int i = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// Prompt user
System.out.print("Please enter " + MyList.length + " integers: ");
  for( i=0; i<MyList.length - 1;i++); {
    MyList[i] = input.nextInt();
    // Output result
    System.out.println("The 5 integers are: "+ MyList[i] +"   ");
  }
```

Output:

```
Please enter 5 integers: 11 12 13 14 15
The 5 integers are : 11
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY9sX.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

1.Remove the semicolon after for loop declaration

```
for(i = 0; i < MyList.length -1 ; i++) ; {
    //your code..
}
```

2.While giving input don't type it in a single line like - `11 12 13 ...` in the console as you are using `input.nextInt()`
Rather type one input at once
`11` hit **enter**
`12` hit **enter**
...
Just like that until the loop ends.

**A friendly advice**
Gather your basic knowledge of `JAVA` then ask for help here.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the semi colon at the end of `for`
 loop statement.the semicolon tells the compiler that it is the end of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

For loops do not need a semicolon after the brackets:

```
for(i = 0; i < MyList.length - 1; i++) {
    //Code
}
```

Currently java thinks there is nothing inside the loop. This means that it is only doing your code once, outside the loop.

It's also worth noting that your code will produce an output like this:

```
The 5 integers are : 11
The 5 integers are : 12
The 5 integers are : 13
...
```

This is because you print one line every time you do a loop. If you want them all to on one line, you might want to do something like this:

```
String output = "";
for(i = 0; i < MyList.length - 1; i++) {
    //Code
    output += MyList[i] + " ";
}
System.out.println("The 5 integers are: " + output);
```

This should add each integer to a string. It will then print the whole array at once, because it is outside the loop.

For future reference, you'll probably find an answer faster if you look up some existing help on the part you are struggling with. There are many good examples and tutorials on for loops (and almost anything else!) out there.

Comment: Thank you for all your help it worked, I'm quite sure I'll be asking for help again sometime in the future. I hope everyone have a great holiday.

Comment: @Bill No problem! If there's an answer that helped most, remember you can click 'accept' to help others find the right solution.